# Null input in a text file

Tags: bash

I have a script that creates users in Linux as well as Oracle, when I create multiple users I use the following:

```
      cat /path/path/file.txt | while read USER PASS ORAUSER ROLE 
       do
```

However I had the misfortune of leaving the role blank and it did some horrible things to my users access. I was wondering how I can check if the text has an empty variable.

Answer (score 3):

Ways to check if a variable is empty:

```
# bash
if [[ -z $var ]]; then
        echo var is empty
fi

# POSIX sh
if [ -z "$var" ]; then
        echo var is empty
fi
printf %s\\n "${var:-var is unset or null}"
: "${var:=default value for var}"
```

This still doesn't solve the problem of missing or misaligned fields in your input file.  If the `ORAUSER` field is missing the `ORAUSER` variable will get assigned the value of the `ROLE` field.  If there are too many fields, the last variable, `ROLE`, will get all the extra fields.  I would recommend switching your text file format to use a separator that is not whitespace, so that empty fields are explicitly delimited.  For example, `/etc/passwd` uses colons (`:`).

If you haven't yet, I would also recommend reading [BashFAQ 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for some collective wisdom on properly parsing text files line-by-line / field-by-field in shell scripts and `bash` specifically.

Comment: That worked, I added the colons to the text file and used your example to come up with this: